# Find solution of homegenous system in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

General solution of A*x=b in MATLAB is given by

```
x=A\b
```

for example

```
A = [2 -1 1; 1 2 3; 3 0 -1]

A =

     2    -1     1
     1     2     3
     3     0    -1

b = [8; 9; 3]

b =

     8
     9
     3

x = A\b

x =

    2.0000
   -1.0000
    3.0000
```

what about  solution of system  `A*x=0`?please help me

Testing on singular matrix

```
A=[1 2 3;2 1 4;3 3 7]

A =

     1     2     3
     2     1     4
     3     3     7

>> det(A)

ans =

     0
b=[0;0;0];
>> linsolve(A,b)
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled.
         Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = 1.903239e-017.

ans =

     0
     0
     0
```

@Robert P.

is this correct?

```
A=[2 3 1;-1 3 1;1 6 2]

A =

     2     3     1
    -1     3     1
     1     6     2

>> det(A);
>> det(A)

ans =

     0

>> [U S V]=svd(A);
>> x=V(:,end);
>> A*x

ans =

  1.0e-015 *

    0.2220
    0.2220
    0.4441
```

Comment: In your second `A` you clearly have row 3 = row1 + row2, thus a singular matrix.

Comment: @dato: Yes, that is correct! =) As I said in the comments on my answer, you can't assume that a computer program will return exactly zero, due to floating point arithmetic. That answer is essentially zero.

Comment: should i use long format to show directly zero  or?because it is  just  very small number,but directly not zero

Comment: What do you want to do with the answer? Just write it to the screen?

Comment: no no  nothing everything is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Singular value decomposition](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/svd.html), [`svd`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) to get an `x` that satisfies `Ax=0` if there are non-trivial solutions:

```
A = [2 -1 1; 2 -1 1; 3 2 1];
[U S V] = svd(A);
x = V(:,end)

x =

  -0.39057
   0.13019
   0.91132

A*x = 

   0
   0
   0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [2 -1 1; 1 2 3; 3 0 -1]
b = [0; 0; 0]
x = A\b
```

Assuming that "0" stands for a zero vector and not the scalar.

Comment: if matrix has determinant  zero,then solution is again zero vector why?

Answer (score 2):

Ok in your case:

```
>> A = [2 -1 1; 1 2 3; 3 0 -1]

A =

     2    -1     1
     1     2     3
     3     0    -1

>> b = [0; 0; 0]

b =

     0
     0
     0

>> x = A\b

x =

     0
     0
     0
```

Or you can use `linsolve`:

```
>> linsolve(A,b)

ans =

     0
     0
     0
```

---

But if `det(A==0)` you should use the eigenvector corresponds the zero eigenvalue, something like that:

```
>> A = [2 -1 1; 1 2 3; 3 0 -1]

A =

     2    -1     1
     1     2     3
     3     0    -1

>> b = [0; 0; 0]

b =

     0
     0
     0

>> [v m] = eig(A)

v =

    1.0000    0.4472         0
         0    0.8944         0
         0         0    1.0000


m =

     0     0     0
     0     2     0
     0     0     3
```

You will have infinite number of solutions, every vector parallel to `[1 0 0]` will be a solution.

Comment: if  A  has determinant zero?

Comment: yes but  if determinant is zero,then it  have to give non zero solution right?

Comment: no it has infinite number of solutions, please read my last revision. I had some internet problems. now it is completed, hopefully

Comment: i know ,i know that it has infinite solution,i wanted that thanks very much

Comment: i have tested and got following result